# Heroku adds an extra "/checkout" in the URL when completing order with Stripe using Django

Tags: python, django, heroku, stripe-payments

I have a small ecommerce project hosted on Heroku that I've built using Django, when clicking "complete order" on the checkout page I should be taken to the template "checkout_success" but instead I get stuck on the same page due to the URL trying to find a path with an extra "/checkout". I've posted some screenshots below to further explain.

**Checkout app URLS.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from .webhooks import webhook

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.checkout, name='checkout'),
    path('checkout_success/<order_number>',
         views.checkout_success, name='checkout_success'),
    path('cache_checkout_data/', views.cache_checkout_data,
         name='cache_checkout_data'),
    path('wh/', webhook, name='webhook'),
]
```

**Checkout apps view for checkout:**

```
def checkout(request):
    stripe_public_key = settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY
    stripe_secret_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY

    if request.method == 'POST':
        bag = request.session.get('bag', {})

        form_data = {
            'full_name': request.POST['full_name'],
            'email': request.POST['email'],
            'phone_number': request.POST['phone_number'],
            'country': request.POST['country'],
            'postcode': request.POST['postcode'],
            'town_or_city': request.POST['town_or_city'],
            'street_address1': request.POST['street_address1'],
            'street_address2': request.POST['street_address2'],
            'county': request.POST['county'],
        }
        order_form = OrderForm(form_data)
        if order_form.is_valid():
            order = order_form.save(commit=False)
            pid = request.POST.get('client_secret').split('_secret')[0]
            order.stripe_pid = pid
            order.original_bag = json.dumps(bag)
            order.save()
            for item_id, item_data in bag.items():
                try:
                    product = Product.objects.get(id=item_id)
                    if isinstance(item_data, int):
                        order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                            order=order,
                            product=product,
                            quantity=item_data,
                        )
                        order_line_item.save()
                    else:
                        for size, quantity in item_data['items_by_size'].items():
                            order_line_item = OrderLineItem(
                                order=order,
                                product=product,
                                quantity=quantity,
                                product_size=size,
                            )
                            order_line_item.save()
                except Product.DoesNotExist:
                    messages.error(request, (
                        "One of the products in your bag wasn't found in our database. "
                        "Please call us for assistance!")
                    )
                    order.delete()
                    return redirect(reverse('view_bag'))

            request.session['save_info'] = 'save-info' in request.POST
            return redirect(reverse('checkout_success', args=[order.order_number]))
        else:
            messages.error(request, 'There was an error with your form. \
                Please double check your information.')
    else:
        bag = request.session.get('bag', {})
        if not bag:
            messages.error(
                request, "There's nothing in your bag at the moment")
            return redirect(reverse('products'))

        current_bag = bag_contents(request)
        total = current_bag['grand_total']
        stripe_total = round(total * 100)
        stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY
        intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
            amount=stripe_total,
            currency=settings.STRIPE_CURRENCY,
        )

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            try:
                profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
                order_form = OrderForm(initial={
                    'full_name': profile.user.get_full_name(),
                    'email': profile.user.email,
                    'phone_number': profile.default_phone_number,
                    'country': profile.default_country,
                    'postcode': profile.default_postcode,
                    'town_or_city': profile.default_town_or_city,
                    'street_address1': profile.default_street_address1,
                    'street_address2': profile.default_street_address2,
                    'county': profile.default_county,
                })
            except UserProfile.DoesNotExist:
                order_form = OrderForm()
        else:
            order_form = OrderForm()

    if not stripe_public_key:
        messages.warning(request, 'Stripe public key is missing. \
            Did you forget to set it in your environment?')

    template = 'checkout/checkout.html'
    context = {
        'order_form': order_form,
        'stripe_public_key': settings.STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY,
        'client_secret': intent.client_secret,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

**Checkout apps views.py for successful checkout:**

```
def checkout_success(request, order_number):
    """
    Handle successful checkouts
    """
    save_info = request.session.get('save_info')
    order = get_object_or_404(Order, order_number=order_number)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        # Attach the user's profile to the order
        order.user_profile = profile
        order.save()

        # Save the user's info
        if save_info:
            profile_data = {
                'default_phone_number': order.phone_number,
                'default_country': order.country,
                'default_postcode': order.postcode,
                'default_town_or_city': order.town_or_city,
                'default_street_address1': order.street_address1,
                'default_street_address2': order.street_address2,
                'default_county': order.county,
            }
            user_profile_form = UserProfileForm(profile_data, instance=profile)
            if user_profile_form.is_valid():
                user_profile_form.save()

    messages.success(request, f'Order successfully processed! \
        Your order number is {order_number}. A confirmation \
        email will be sent to {order.email}.')

    if 'bag' in request.session:
        del request.session['bag']

    template = 'checkout/checkout_success.html'
    context = {
        'order': order,
    }

    return render(request, template, context)
```

**checkout template:**

```
            <form action="{% url 'checkout' %}" method="POST" id="payment-form">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="rounded px-3 mb-5">
                    <legend class="fieldset-label small text-black px-2 w-auto">Details</legend>
                    {{ order_form.full_name | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.email | as_crispy_field }}
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="rounded px-3 mb-5">
                    <legend class="fieldset-label small text-black px-2 w-auto">Delivery</legend>
                    {{ order_form.phone_number | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.street_address1 | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.street_address2 | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.town_or_city | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.county | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.postcode | as_crispy_field }}
                    {{ order_form.country | as_crispy_field }}
                    <div class="form-check form-check-inline float-right mr-0">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="id-save-info">Save this delivery information to my
                            profile</label>
                        <input class="form-check-input ml-2 mr-0" type="checkbox" id="id-save-info" name="save-info"
                            checked>
                        {% else %}
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="id-save-info">
                            <a class="text-info" href="{% url 'account_signup' %}">Create an account</a> or
                            <a class="text-info" href="{% url 'account_login' %}">login</a> to save this information
                        </label>
                        {% endif %}
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset class="px-3">
                    <legend class="fieldset-label small text-black px-2 w-auto">Payment</legend>
                    <!-- A Stripe card element will go here -->
                    <div class="mb-3" id="card-element"></div>

                    <!-- Used to display form errors -->
                    <div class="mb-3 text-danger" id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="{{ client_secret }}" name="client_secret">
                </fieldset>

                <div class="submit-button text-right mt-5 mb-2">
                    <a href="{% url 'view_bag' %}" class="btn btn-outline-black rounded-0">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Adjust Bag</span>
                    </a>
                    <button id="submit-button" class="btn btn-black rounded-0">
                        <span class="font-weight-bold">Complete Order</span>
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>
                    <p class="small text-danger my-0">
                        <span class="icon">
                            <i class="fas fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                        </span>
                        <span>Your card will be charged <strong>${{ grand_total|floatformat:2 }}</strong></span>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </form>
```

**JS for Stripe payment**

```
// Handle form submit
var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

form.addEventListener('submit', function (ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    card.update({
        'disabled': true
    });
    $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#payment-form').fadeToggle(100);
    $('#loading-overlay').fadeToggle(100);

    var saveInfo = Boolean($('#id-save-info').attr('checked'));
    // From using {% csrf_token %} in the form
    var csrfToken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
    var postData = {
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrfToken,
        'client_secret': clientSecret,
        'save_info': saveInfo,
    };
    var url = '/checkout/cache_checkout_data/';

    $.post(url, postData).done(function () {
        stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: card,
                billing_details: {
                    name: $.trim(form.full_name.value),
                    phone: $.trim(form.phone_number.value),
                    email: $.trim(form.email.value),
                    address: {
                        line1: $.trim(form.street_address1.value),
                        line2: $.trim(form.street_address2.value),
                        city: $.trim(form.town_or_city.value),
                        country: $.trim(form.country.value),
                        state: $.trim(form.county.value),
                    }
                }
            },
            shipping: {
                name: $.trim(form.full_name.value),
                phone: $.trim(form.phone_number.value),
                address: {
                    line1: $.trim(form.street_address1.value),
                    line2: $.trim(form.street_address2.value),
                    city: $.trim(form.town_or_city.value),
                    country: $.trim(form.country.value),
                    postal_code: $.trim(form.postcode.value),
                    state: $.trim(form.county.value),
                }
            },
        }).then(function (result) {
            if (result.error) {
                var errorDiv = document.getElementById('card-errors');
                var html = `
                    <span class="icon" role="alert">
                    <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span>${result.error.message}</span>`;
                $(errorDiv).html(html);
                $('#payment-form').fadeToggle(100);
                $('#loading-overlay').fadeToggle(100);
                card.update({
                    'disabled': false
                });
                $('#submit-button').attr('disabled', false);
            } else {
                if (result.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
                    form.submit();
                }
            }
        });
    }).fail(function () {
        // just reload the page, the error will be in django messages
        location.reload();
    })
```

**Heroku Logs Error:**

***notice the extra "/checkout" in the POST URL.*
[image]

[image]

Same in the browser console URL

I've tried an array things from adding and taking away "/" in my settings.py file and other URL paths. I'm sure this is something im overlooking but i've been stuck with this bug for days now. If anyone could help that would be great! And if any additional info is needed i'll be happy to provide. Thanks!

Comment: show your code where you build your url to redirect in `html` or `view`, look like you build it as relative to current page and that is why you get extra "path"

Comment: @AndreyMaslov Hi, i've updated my question with the code for my checkout view and checkout_success view. Please et me know if you need anything else.

Comment: can't find in your code where you try to builld `cache_checkout_data` url it might be in html page in `<form action='...' method=POST>` or in your `webhook` view

Comment: @AndreyMaslov Apologis, i've updated the question with the full form from my checkout template

Comment: still can't find problem(. Do you redirect with `jQuery`? if so, show it, please

Comment: @AndreyMaslov I overlooked the JS being a problem. I have a var url directing me to '/checkout/cache_checkout_data/' but im not sure if this is whats actually causing the issue. I've updated the question with the JS code.

Comment: probably your var url was like this `checkout/cache_checkout_data/`(without starting slash), after you add this slash everything should be fine

Comment: @AndreyMaslov Unfortunately i still have the error with the slash

Comment: probably your browser get you .js file from cache, can you `console.log(url);` before your `$.post` to be sure, that `url` variable contains what you need

Comment: @AndreyMaslov When i console.log(url) i get locally i get the correct url going to "/checkout/cache_checkout_data" should there be more in my url variable?

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py in checkout_success view You should use

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checkout_success',args=(order)))
```

instead of

```
template = 'checkout/checkout_success.html'
context = {
    'order': order,
}

return render(request, template, context)
```

Comment: don't build your urls like that `'checkout_success/'+str(order)` use `reverse` function for this purpose

Comment: @AndreyMaslov yeah you are right , just edited the answer . It was the straightforward yet not the best way to do it

Comment: @helodevZcoder thanks for the response. I get an error saying "unexpected EOF while parsing" when using "HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('checkout_success',args=(order))"

Comment: @DelroyBrown i think it is a syntax problem or identention. It is a return HttpResponseRedirect

Answer (score 0):

thanks I solved this, I problems, this problems was in js